# Mysql find all items not in the same table for each type of field2

Tags: mysql

I have a translations table (simplified) like this:

`id`, `lang`, `item`, `value`

I want to find which items exists for one language that do not exist for some of the other languages, so I'm looking for orphaned language items.

I've tried something like

```
SELECT            a.*
FROM              translations a
NATURAL LEFT JOIN translations b
WHERE             b.item IS NULL
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Another option is to iterate through all languages asking for items in `lang_1` that are not in `lang_2`, but this needs several queries.

Is there an easy way to filter this in sql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by generating all the combinations of languages and words and then determining which ones do not exist.  The first part can be done using a `cross join`.  The second part has a couple of options.  Here is a `left join` version:

```
select i.item, l.lang
from (select distinct item from translations) i cross join
     (select distinct lang from translations) l left join
     translations t
     on t.item = i.item and t.lang = l.lang
where t.item is null;
```

This will give the list of all `item`/`lang` pairs that are not in the `translations` table.

Comment: Awesome !

Let me correct only one sentence, where it reads t.lang = i.lang it should be t.lang = l.lang.

Many thanks, it works perfectly.